# Limitar barra de rolagem de acordo com o tamanho da div

Tags: jquery, html, css, rolamento

Existe algum jeito de limitar a `barra de rolagem` da página de acordo com o tamanho (altura) de uma `div`?

Digamos que eu tenho um site como qualquer outro, mas ao abrir uma `box` flutuante com altura de **1000px**, quero que o `scroll` do mouse trave quando alcançar o fim dessa `div`, mesmo que o site continue para baixo, só permitir a rolagem para cima. Claro que quando esta `div` for fechada, o `scroll` volta ao normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim é possível, existem maneiras diferentes, uma delas é usando JavaScript/jQuery para saber as dimensões e posição do elemento para poder sincronizar o scroll com esses valores.

Se usar [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) pode saber onde o elemento começa e somando-lhe o [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) sabe onde ele acaba. Depois precisa saber o valor do *scroll* e isso pode obter com [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Para finalizar, e uma vez que o *evento scroll* não é cancelável, tem de re-escrever o valor do scroll caso ele passe "os limites".

Sugestão de código:

```
var ultimoScroll;
var dialogPosition = $('#seu_dialog').offset().top;
var dialogHeight = $('#seu_dialog').outerHeight();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > dialogPosition + dialogHeight.outerHeight() || scroll < dialogPosition) $(window).scrollTop(ultimoScroll);
    else ultimoScroll = scroll;
});
```

Este é o esqueleto do que precisa. Como não deu nenhum código HTML/CSS/JS deixo um exemplo inventado por mim que com uma adaptação desse código que referi em cima: http://jsfiddle.net/a825dnfm/

Comment: Olá Sergio, adaptei seu código ao meu script e apenas corrigi alí o `dialogHeight.outerHeight()` para somente `dialogHeight`. Seu código funcionou bem como eu queria, mas ele está travando o scroll no final da div, ou seja, a div sobe toda até o topo e trava no finalzinho dela. Teria que travar quando o final da div ficar no final da tela, para não poder subir mais.

Comment: Claro, era apenas fazer um cálculo diminuindo a altura da janela e pronto! Modifiquei o `if` para: `if (scroll > dialogPosition + ( dialogHeight - SC(window).height() )`, obrigado!!

Comment: Sergio, você sabe me dizer como fazer para este código funcionar em mobile? Pois o site é responsivo e visualizado em smartphones ou tablets, esse esquema de scroll não funciona.

Comment: @Ricardo o código deve funcionar em mobile. Sei que o jQuery não suporta mobile oficialmente, daí existir o jQuery mobile. Se tiver problemas em mobile coloque um exemplo com o seu código para testar.

Comment: Ah tah. Não linkei uma biblioteca mobile do jQuery. Vou fazer isso então. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize css. Com o atributo overflow você pode determinar o que acontece quando o tamanho da um objeto é maior que o espaço onde ele está. Por exemplo:

```
#id {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Quer dizer que quando a largura e o comprimento da tag body forem maiores que a tela, não haverá rolagem. No seu caso o mais indicado seria:

```
#id {
    max-height: 1000px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```